# Restore backup global using pgadmin

Tags: postgresql, backup, restore

I created backup global by rightclicking Postgres 15 in pgadmin
[image]
It generates `.sql` file. How do i restore the backup global in pgadmin ? I tried searching on google but didnt found the answer

Comment: Nevermind, i just opened the file with notepad and turns out it was only sql query inside, i can just run it one by one manually

Answer (score 0):

You have to restore a "plain" format dump (which is an SQL script) with `psql`. pgAdmin won't work, unless it is a schema-only dump or you activated "use insert commands (`--inserts`), because `COPY` data are nixed in with the statements.

You can start a "psql tool" in pgAdmin and use `\i dumpfile` to import the backup.